# Handling Mono Inside Flux Flatmap

Tags: java, functional-programming, project-reactor

I have a Flux of strings. For each string, I have to make a remote call. But the problem is that the method that makes the remote call actually returns a Mono of the response (obviously since corresponding to a single request, there'll be a single response).

What should be the correct pattern to handle such cases? One solution I can think of is to make serial (or parallel) calls for the stream elements and reduce the responses to a single one and return.

Here's the code:

```
fluxObj.flatmap(a -> makeRemoteCall(a)//converts the Mono of the response to a Flux).reduce(...)
```

I am being unable to wrap my head around inside the `flatmap`.The `makeRemoteCall` method returns a `Mono`. But the `flatmap` returns a `Flux` of the response. First, why is this happening? Second, does it mean that the returned `Flux` contains a single response object (that was returned in the `Mono`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `mapper Function` returns a `Mono`, then it means that there will be (at most) one derived value **for each source element in the `Flux`**.

Having the `Function` return:

- an empty Mono (eg. `Mono.empty()`) for a given value means that this source value is "ignored"
- a valued `Mono` (like in your example) means that this source value is asynchronously mapped to another specific value
- a `Flux` with several derived values for a given value means that this source value is asynchronously mapped to several values

For instance, given the following `flatMap`:

```
Flux.just("A", "B")
    .flatMap(v -> Mono.just("value" + v))
```

Subscribing to the above `Flux<String>` and printing the emitted elements would yield:

```
valueA
valueB
```

Another fun example: with delays, one can get out of order results. Like this:

```
Flux.just(300, 100)
    .flatMap(delay -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(delay))
                          .thenReturn(delay + "ms")
    )
```

would result in a `Flux<String>` that yields:

```
100ms
300ms
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see documentation [flatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-), you can found answers to your questions:

> Transform the elements emitted by this Flux asynchronously into Publishers, then flatten these inner publishers into a single Flux, sequentially and preserving order using concatenation.

Long story in short,

```
@Test
public void testFlux() {
    Flux<String> oneString = Flux.just("1");

    oneString
        .flatMap(s -> testMono(s))
        .collectList()
        .subscribe(integers -> System.out.println("elements:" + integers));       

}

private Mono<Integer> testMono(String s) {
    return Mono.just(Integer.valueOf(s + "0"));
}
```

***mapper*** - `s -> testMono(s)` where `testMono(s)` is Publisher (in your case `makeRemoteCall(a)`), it transforms a type of my `oneString` to ***Integer***.

I collected Flux result to List, and printed it. Console output:

```
elements:[10]
```

It means result Flux after `flatMap` operator contains just one element.

Comment: this answer is misleading, as it uses the least generic case of having a single string in the source `Flux` to begin with... Having 2 strings would yield a list of 2 elements.